# SHOW information with recent date on top and pagination in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I have read various page but I still get an ascending order for date.
here is what I've tried :

```
$sqx = "SELECT * FROM $hislist ORDER BY (STR_TO_DATE(date,'%D %d-%M-%Y%H:%i:%s')) DESC";
```

I stored date as `VARCHAR` so I tried with `STR_TO_DATE` but I still got :

```
Wed 22-Mar-2017 15:29:52

Wed 22-Mar-2017 15:51:04

Thu 23-Mar-2017 17:12:34
```

I want the recent date to be on top.

and if you can help me with this, I would like to ask about pagination, some easy ways to do a pagination like 30 most recent records on the first page and so on for the next 30.

I'm sorry about my last question. I'm in rush.
I appreciate for all of your help and looking forward for your answers.

Comment: Everyone's always in a rush. That's why we generally ask clear questions, so as not to bother our fellow comrades in arms too much in understanding the question in the first place - let alone have them write our programs. It'd be kind of you to do the same!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqx = "SELECT * FROM $hislist ORDER BY (STR_TO_DATE(date,'%a %d-%M-%Y%H:%i:%s')) DESC";
```

Just try above code.
Hope this will help.